# grafana dashboard for default telegraf config

Tags: sample, influxdb, grafana

I just set up influxdb (v0.9), grafana (v2.1), and telegraf (v0.1.9). They are running fine, telegraf puts its metrics to influxdb, and in grafana I can add graphs based on these values.
However, I have to do so manually for each single measurement that is recorded, including figuring out what they signify & in which unit.

Is there a dashboard file to import into grafana, which contains useful graphs for all the default telegraf plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such file yet exists, although both the InfluxDB and Grafana open source projects would welcome community contributions on this issue!